# How does my computer know that it is connected to the Internet?

Tags: windows, networking

Sorry for asking such a mundane question, but I'm suddenly curious. If I open the network connections dialog on my Windows machine, it shows me a cute little picture of my computer connecting to a router and then to a globe (labeled Internet). What is Windows trying to connect to in order for it to decide that the computer has Internet connectivity? I assume there is no IP4 address for 'The Internet', so where is it going? Is it just sending a ping to an address back at the Microsoft home office? If that address were to disappear, would my window's machine suddenly decide that it no longer has a route to the Internet? Would Windows boxes that were 'close' to that address incorrectly report that they could get to the Internet when they couldn't.

I'll stop now before this gets too silly. But seriously, what criteria does a Windows box use to determine that it has Internet connectivity? I'm assuming that Linux and iOS systems have an equivalent feature. Do they use the same criteria?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general IP address that is used for 'the internet' is `8.8.8.8` - or Google.com.

If you can ping it, and get a web page from it, then there's a pretty good chance you can get to at least *some* of the internet.

But for specifically Windows - [Network Connectivity Status Indicator](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee126135(WS.10).aspx) - it uses a different domain: dns.msftncsi.com

It will (unless disabled by GPO):

- resolve the name, and verify it has the 'right' IP (`131.107.255.255`
  `fd3e:4f5a:5b81::1` )
- Perform a HTTP get to this address and check it gets a result. [NCSI](http://www.msftncsi.com/ncsi.txt)

Presumably if different responses are retrieved, then it can tell if it has a wi-fi login or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Your intuitions seem correct. I am not on a Windows machine but you could find out by firing `netstat` and then connecting.

Answer (score 0):

If I was programming this I'd make Ping, TCP and HTTP requests. Some devices are connected through proxies such as firewalls, captive portals and others. the only way to be sure is to send something and receive a reply.

My Android device for example can detect captive portals. It probably does that by trying to HTTP connect somewhere.